# Most efficient way to poll multiple devices in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, polling

I've read a lot about this topic, but still am not sure what to do.

First, the situation: I have software written in C# using .NET 4.5 that polls up to 64 devices on a CAN network that I communicate with via USB using a third party API from the device manufacturer. The purpose is to provide the user with realtime updates of temperature, pressure, and other values like that from some sensors.

Currently I create a System.Threading.Thread for every device which runs a while loop that queries the device for the relevant info, saves updates to SQL Server via Entity Framework, then sleeps for 1.25 seconds.

This runs ok on smaller systems with ~20 or fewer devices, but on a large install with 50+ devices it runs very slowly. I think that my problem is the overhead of creating so many threads. And it doesn't help that I'm stuck with a crappy Atom processor, although at least this one is quad core unlike the previous system I used that was dual core.

So, I've been trying to make the process more efficient. Everything I read seems to point to Task.Run() being the more effective way of doing something like this, but this software could potentially be running for weeks or months at a time, which I THINK means I would need to run it with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning. But I've read conflicting things on this, so I'm not sure. But if that is the case, then my understanding is that TPL will just start up a new dedicated thread anyways, so it seems like that would still have the overhead I'm trying to avoid.

So, as you can see, I'm pretty lost on this topic. I don't know if I should just give Task.Run() a try, and see what happens, or if there's a whole different way I should do this.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). For each device create a timer, configure it and do the work in the callback. The callbacks will execute on thread pool threads.

Comment: I take it that a Timer would have less overhead because it wouldn't be spinning up a new thread, but instead would be using the threads available on the thread pool? Also, is there any risk of garbage collection problems? With it running so long would I have to call GC.KeepAlive() or anything?

Comment: The Garbage Collector only collects objects that are no longer referenced by anything. So as long as your variables don't go out of scope (or you set them to `null`) the objects they're pointing to won't be garbage collected.

Comment: The best method is to use USB Receive Events instead of timer.  Make each 64 serial port an instance of the same class so you don't have to duplicate code.  Then make a List() of devices which contains all the port classes.

Comment: The thing is, the API I'm using doesn't provide events, polling is my only option. I have to call something like var temperatureValue = _apiObject.GetCurrentTemperature(_currentChannelNumber); each time I want to get info from a sensor. That's why I have to poll. Also, I want to say thanks to everyone for the help so far.

Comment: While having 50 threads that wait most of the time is wasteful, it should not cause any significant performance issues (assuming you can waste 50 MB of RAM, which you probably can). You should profile your code to see what's actually causing the issue, instead of trying to fix it by guessing what the issue is.

Comment: That's fair. I definitely have no RAM concerns. Will do.

Comment: If you are still using a thread-per-device, I would advise adding a small delay before spawning the next thread. I've had performance problems before with a similar strategy as yours. In my case, a large number of  threads were waking up at basically the same time, choking the CPU and/or the IO subsystem.  The suggested delay caused the threads to wake up orderly, in a sequential fashion and removed the scalability problem.

Comment: Thanks, BlueStrat! I'll try that. I've appreciated everyone's input, but since yours seems to be the one that most closely addresses my original question, if you'll put it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted for the time being unless someone else just comes in and blows me away with their answer.